# Scrolltop animation locking scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple fields.  In each field, the page scroll to bottom

```
$('.my_input').on('change', function(e){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("html, body").height()}, "slow");
}
```

This works fine, but if i try to scroll to top, the page "freeze" the scroll in bottom, releasing after several attemps.

How to fix it?

Tks

Comment: Try to call stop on elements you're animating (html and body) on scroll to stop the scrolling animation.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: can you set up a fiddle for the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the event is firing itself again and again. You can try using `one` to fire the event only once.

See the code below. Also please share sufficient code to replicate the problem, if this doesn't help you as their maybe another reason for the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.my_input').one('change', function(e){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("html, body").height()}, "slow");
});
});
```

```css
.my_input{
display:block;
margin-bottom:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="my_input"/>
<input type="text" class="my_input"/>
<input type="text" class="my_input"/>
```

Comment: The page still holds the scroll a little, but it scroll up now. Thanks :)